# How to set bar border color here?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I set the border color of the bars here when I use ggQC to draw pareto plot? I don't want it to be black. Thank you in advance.

```
library(ggQC)
df <- data.frame(x=c("1","2","3","4"),y=c(100,50,20,4))
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + stat_pareto(point.size = 2,              
              line.color = "black",              
              bars.fill = c("#3399FF")) + theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: The colour argument is somehow fixed to black(and less flexible). Only option might be to use `layer` or contact the author to make this more flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE:** I have created a clone of the repo and added a flexible `bars.colour` argument that can be used to do this. Please note that the author(s) has/have not yet(and I'm not sure if they will) approved this. My apologies if it is against their contribution policy.

You can download it as follows:

```
devtools::install_github("Nelson-Gon/ggQC")
```

Then do:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + stat_pareto(point.size = 2,              
                                        line.color = "black",              
                                        bars.fill = c("#3399FF"),
                                        bars.colour = "red")
```

Result:
[image]